# Python and Bash compare numbers

Tags: python, numeric-data

If I run the following in bash, i will get correct answer

```
# if [ 2.0000000000000000000000000001 > 2 ] ; then echo " True "; else echo " False " ; fi
 True
#
```

But if run in python IDLE

```
>>> if 2.00000000000000001 > 2.0:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"


false
>>>
```

Python can't compare the number right?

I think I have the answer. Python only use the 10 digs for the floating numbers.

```
>>> c=2.00000000001232
>>> print c
2.00000000001
>>> d= 2.00000000003234
>>> print d
2.00000000003
>>> e=2.000000000049
>>> print e
2.00000000005
>>>
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: >>> c=2.00000000001232
>>> print c
2.00000000001
>>> d= 2.00000000003234
>>> print d
2.00000000003
>>> e=2.000000000049
>>> print e
2.00000000005
>>>

Comment: FYI, `bash` doesn't support floating point numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't successfully compared the numbers in bash, you've only tested that "bash" (the `test` command) has successfully tested the length of the string `2.0000000000000000000000000001` and redirected the non-existent output into a file named `2`.

You would want the `-gt` operator, except:

```
[ 2.0000000000000000000000000001 -gt 2 ] && echo yes
```

> -bash: [: 2.0000000000000000000000000001: integer expression expected

You might think of:

```
[[ 2.0000000000000000000000000001 > 2 ]] && echo yes
```

and get:

> yes

except you're not comparing integers at that point, you're sorting strings:

```
[[ 9 > 11 ]] && echo yes
```

> yes

To compare floating point numbers in Python, see Stack Overflow for more details, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python)